# Homopolar motors - a curious realisation

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

So I've been chasing down devices with unique operational characteristics looking for potential in energy generation and I ran into these things: homopolar motors.

About 9/10 of these things are a wire on a battery and a magnet and the professional variants are used as low voltage high current generators and use a disk spinning perpendicular to a static magnetic field to generate power, taking energy from the rim and axle.

Anyway, it got me thinking about it and I realised something about when these motors are running. After the stator or rotor has been powered for five RL time constants, there's no more reactive component to the engine and all the supply sees, no matter how much or how little work the rotor does, is the ohmic resistance of the coils.

With no current alternation and no reactive component, you could have 10,000 ampere-turns of magnetic field torquing the rotor and the coil resistance could be approx. 6 ohms and only need 0.5 amps supplied at 12 volts, if you were patient enough to wind 20,000 turns.

The rotor is torqued by the strength of the field and being torqued doesn't take field strength away or change the steady powering of the coil. 100% of the actual input power is turned to heat via resistive heating. The inertia in the rotor essentially isn't coming from your input power, it comes from the interaction of the rotor with the infinitely spiraling vortex shaped field of the stator.

The input power determines the strength of that field, but no conversion of energy is actually taking place between the input and the output. The input is 100% consumed by joule heating.

So normally people make these in science class with a battery, a magnet and a folded strand of wire or they copy Faraday's design using a disk rotor. But I figure there must be a better way to make these things and make them more practical and useful.

I figure that if a coil is used then the supply voltage could be kept low since wire resistance is not generally high anyway but the supply current could be dropped as well since a coil could make more efficient use of the amperage for field generation.

What do my fellow engineers think?

Any suggestions for how I should tackle this?

Comment: Paragraph 4 says, "*6 ohms and only need 0.5 amps supplied at 12 volts ...*". Check the maths on that!

Comment: I never specified awg, but 22 gauge is only 16.14 ohms for 1000 feet. If you were willing to use 14 gauge wire, you'd have 2250 feet of cable to wind before reaching 6 ohm. But that's not the main point. The main point was that the motor runs while presenting the circuit with only wire resistance as the load after 5 RL time constants. That doesn't mean efficient, but it does mean not directly related.

Comment: I just find it really interesting because the motor should basically look like a solenoid to the powering circuit

Comment: If you have 250' of 22 AWG facing a 0.5 tesla magnet the force on the magnet will be "F = B * I * L = 0.5 * 1 * 75 m = 37.5 N" and the resistance of that length of wire, plus the parts of the wraps the magnet doesn't see should be about 12 ohms(750' total wire used let's say). Since the current is set at 1 amp, that means 12 V to supply that current. If the magnets are at a radius of 0.04 m on the rotor, that's 1.5 newton meters of torque for an input of 12 watts.

Comment: I'm not an expert on magnetic circuits, but I suspect that you'll only get 0.5 T when the magnetic circuit is a closed loop of high-permeability material such as ferrous metals. Once you introduce an air gap the field strength will collapse.

Comment: the 0.5 T is in reference to the strength of the external magnetic field to the wire, not the field strength of the solenoid. ceramic magnets range in strength from 0.5 T - 1 T and Neodyniums are a lot better at around 1T - 1.4 T typically. I'm using 5mm thick ceramic magnets so I played it safe and estimated 0.5 T.

This is Lorenz force calculation for a wire in an external magnetic field. "F = I*L*B*sin(theta)". Since the wires are perpendicular we simplify sin(theta) as 1. https://isaacphysics.org/concepts/cp_lorentz_force?stage=all

Comment: Thanks for the edits to my post btw, I'm autistic and spelling isn't always my strongest suit, it would have taken me the next 2 hours of coming back and re-reading over and over again to catch all those

Comment: for reference to magnet strength: https://www.stanfordmagnets.com/rare-earth-magnet-types-and-uses.html

Comment: You should approach this by not thinking you have discovered a great new way to generate power.  100% of the principles involved are known, and trying to put significant power through one would soon point out its shortcomings to you.  These motors are used to demonstrate principles, there are better ways to generate power.

Comment: Not interesting in making something that's already been done. I want to make a high performance homopolar motor and measure it's performance characteristics for science.

It's my dream to find an equivalents to the carnot cycle/refrigeration cycle but to work on gradients other than thermal gradients.

I'm thinking that this has potential to be a "refrigeration cycle" style situation using electricity to effect in the rotor innertia. Kinda like how a heat pump makes heat flow backwards with C.O.P. > 1.

Answer (score 0):

The first way to increase the homopolar/unipolar performance is to research possible methods of removing the friction from said brushes such as Tesla's own patent US406968, the "Dynamo-Electric Machine". using a flexible conductive belt between the rims of two such discs. Then imagine, as he did, multiplying thier output by interconnecting the axils of multiple such dualpolar discs.